# Jquery/Javascript Automatically select check box and sumit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new here and in HTML and other codes. I am starting a new social website at wapka but I have a problem. The problem is I want to add a user to a group according to their profile (gender) variable automatically.

Example: If a user selects female during registration she will be added to a group named her and I don't want them to see and click any button. I know how to hide but I don't know how auto select it for them. Here is the code to add a user to a group:

```
<form method="post" action="setgroup_2.xhtml" >
   <input type="checkbox" name="set_group[1]" value="1"  />
    his<br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="set_group[1]" value="1" />
    her<br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="set_group[1]" value="1"  />
   <input type="hidden" name="agroups" value="12=1489bf637bbadc1abce91ee565082bf3"  />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Set groups" />
</form>
```

I hope readers can understand and help me.

Comment: Use [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) to set the value of a hidden input (`<input type="hidden" name="group" />`)

Comment: please share your code, errors. It will help you to get the best possible answer for your question.

Comment: what i want is a javascript or a jquery code to automatically add the user to a group and submit. something like this. <script language="javascript"> var
gender=':user-prvar-2';
if (gender>=male) { document.write
("his"); }
else if (gender>=female)
{ document.write("her"); } </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here is an example of what you want to do.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_checkbox_value3

And here is an example of dealing with checkbox true,false value. 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp

I also think that in your case there should be radio button not checkbox. That's because there is only one case of gender. (sorry for my English)

Comment: Thank you very much but i have 2 cases of gender male and female